# Replace with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, replace

Hi Im trying to replace some html with Jquery, this is what I got so far.

```
 $(".old").html($(".new").html());
```

This almost work. Only that the .new is being copied, instead of replacing.
I wan't to Cut/Paste instead of Copy/Paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work: `$('.old').empty().append($('.new'));`. It would move the element instead of duplicating.

Comment: I changed `.html('')` to `.empty()` since that looks better.